# Should TV series tags be suffixed with -tv or -tv-series?

Tags: discussion, tags, tv

We have some TV series tags formatted like [revenge-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revenge-tv) and [sex-and-the-city-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex-and-the-city-tv) while others are formatted like [thriller-tv-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thriller-tv-series). Shouldn't we have a standard way to suffix these tags? In my opinion, they should have the suffix **-tv-series** at the end as long as the tag doesn't exceed the 25 word limit.

I am concerned about TV series which have same name as movie. For example we have [incredible-hulk-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incredible-hulk-tv) which I think should be renamed to [incredible-hulk-tv-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incredible-hulk-tv-series).

Comment: i hate the idea of another tag about tv... its bad enough we have the "tv-series" meta tag...

Comment: @TylerShads i think you have not got what i am saying. Or i am not understanding what you are saying. I am saying that naming a tv series like [tag:abc-tv-series] is better then naming it [tag:abc-tv].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all making a standard is a very good idea, of course. But because of that I disagree that `-tv-series` should be used.

The problem is that this tag extension is **only a meta-appendage that should be used only if really necessary**. Thus it should also be **as small as possible** and shouldn't contribute too much to the already pretty short tag name limit of 25 characters (so that not other, more important, non-meta information needs to be stripped from the tag name instead). So `-tv` is a much shorter extension than `-tv-series`, yet IMHO **conveys pretty much the same information more concisely** (what else should it mean, we also use `-1987` instead of `-from-1987`).

While one could reason the way you did, using `-tv-series` whenever possible and `-tv` only when it gets too long, this would result in exactly the same tag mess that we have now. Introducing a standard should result in **just a single way to tag those cases**, and for that single way the shorter `-tv` is a much better choice, I think.

Comment: +1, I will not say i am agree/disagree with you but we should chose something up. I mean currently it looked messed up to me. So choosing a standard is good and i am ok with `-tv` too but lets see what other thought.

Comment: @AnkitSharma *"but we should chose something up. I mean currently it looked messed up to me."* - Of course we should, nothing else does this answer say.

Comment: I think community is agree with you and even i thinks its a rite way to keep it short.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Thanks. Now only somebody just needs to find all those `-tv-series` tags (and coordinate a non-front-page-uglifying edit session ;-)).

Comment: why you made it to [tag:teen-wolf], i mean its going to confuse it with movie now.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Because there is no question about the movie at all here, and this is a case where you yourself said in the question that a `-tv` appendage isn't necessary, if I remember correctly (or at least a case not addressed in the question at all).

Comment: i said **I am concerned about TV series which have same name as movie**. And its the same case. We similarly don't have question on buffy movie but we still have -tv in its end.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Oh, so I misinterpreted your intentions. That screams for a major extension of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging is an imperfect way to catalog (anyone can add a tag, trying to impose authority control on user tags can be exhaustive, and most tagging systems only allow searching on one term at a time). The benefits to open tagging (collaboration, relativity to the individual user, social aspect, open-endedness) don't really add much benefit on this site.

The purpose of the tags is to make questions searchable and groupable. Ideally they would be limited to things people would actually like to limit by. With keyword searching available, many of our tags are redundant.

- I agree with @ChristianRau that appending the title of a TV show with **-TV** when it is not clearly a TV show makes sense (and it is shorter that -TV series). I think the appendage is unnecessary when there is no ambiguity.
- I also agree with @TylerShads that having a TV-Series tag is useless, as are many of our tags.

If we are going to attempt to create structure for our tags, maybe we want to make a list of things people might want to search on:

- name of show or movie
- name of actor, director
- genre (we could create a list - romance, horror, western, Bollywood...)
- type of question - identify (for identifying actor or title), plot explanation, analysis, production, soundtrack, or trivia ("what was the first..." or "what's that poster on the wall in...")

We have odd tags like specific-scene, ending, prequel, imdb - who is going to want to limit their search to all the "specific-scene" or "prequel" questions?

**Alternately**, we could just let people tag away, because that's how tags work in an open system. Maybe we worry too much about how they are used and whether they are useful at all. How many of you ever click on a tag other than a title to limit the list of questions to those? Maybe no one is really using the tags and it doesn't matter? Maybe letting the user choose his own tags gives him "ownership" of his question, just like picking a title for it does. Maybe we need to think about how well we could manage imposing structure on our tags if we had 3 or 5 or 10 times as many questions? If our goal is to grow BIG, we might need to come to grips with the fact that ultimately we aren't going to be able to do anything about the tags.

So there's an answer from both sides of the coin!

Comment: Good points. Just a small response to one of the various interesting points: *"If our goal is to grow BIG, we might need to come to grips with the fact that ultimately we aren't going to be able to do anything about the tags."* - That's the reason why we need to set as good and unambiguous an example *before* the site grows too big to manage.