# Create Tags for every movie I want to ask something about?

Tags: discussion, faq, tags

A few days ago I earned the 'create tags' privilege. My question for this privilege is short and simple: Should I create a tag for **every** movie which has no tag yet?

I don't want to create a tag for every movie on the planet ;-) Only movies I want to ask a question about at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now first of all, **you can't create a tag if there isn't a question** about the movie yet, neither should you. Tags are only created when asking a question by just adding it to the question.

But when asking a question about a movie, then **yeah, indeed you should.** It is long-standing, accepted and applied policy on this site to tag each and every question with the respective movie title it is about, if any specific one. This is also the reason why this is one of the few sites that are *exempt* from the general SE rule that deletes tags with only one question after some time.

There are some intricacies to this policy touched in related questions:

- [What's the policy on abbreviating titles of Movies & TV Shows?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/49)
- [Rules for multiple media using the same name](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1427/49)
- [Should TV series tags be suffixed with -tv or -tv-series?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1070/49)

But those are different questions on their own.

Answer (score 0):

I agree totally with what @Napoleon Wilson has said about the site's policy. However, I just want to clarify something. You say: *Should I create a tag for every movie which has no tag yet?*

**Obviously, no**. Don't go on a mass creation spree where you create a new tag for every single movie in history, regardless of its activity on this site.

Your next comment was: *I don't want to create a tag for every movie on the planet ;-) Only movies I want to ask a question about at the moment.*

**Yes.** That's the way to go about it. If you have a question and a tag doesn't exist, create one. Otherwise don't.

That might be incredibly obvious, but given the wording of your question I just wanted to absolutely clarify it.

Comment: Well, the approach of creating a tag for *every possible* movie isn't only invalid, it's also plain **impossible**. Because how do you create a tag? You put it onto a fitting question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Ah okay then. I thought you could create stand alone tags and assign them later - which would be a little silly. Thanks for the clarification.