# Tag for 2011 TV show "Episodes"

Tags: discussion, tags

We've just gotten [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31248/episodes-season-4-are-matt-leblancs-financial-troubles-a-caricature-of-nicola), based on the 2011 TV series Episodes. It's the first question based on that show, so I created a tag for it.

As [episodes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episodes) would be a fairly generic tag and might lead people to use it for any questions based on *any* tv show episodes, I created a tag called [episodes-tv-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episodes-tv-series).

Are people happy with this, or would they prefer [episodes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episodes) or perhaps a combination of the show and its start date: [episodes-2011](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episodes-2011)?

*Note: I should this is a very isolated case and isn't worthy of a colossal discussion. I'm really just trying to gauge opinion on it. The old maxim still stands that usually it will be [nameofseries](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nameofseries) or [nameofseries-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nameofseries-tv) if necessary.*

Comment: [We decided the tag suffix as -tv rather then -tv-series](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/should-tv-series-tags-be-suffixed-with-tv-or-tv-series) but still i think episodes-tv will be vague and you suggestion is ok.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: I was aware of that discussion but thought the same as you (nice diamond by the way ;))

Comment: And I was just about to reformat the tag into the "proper" `episodes` when I thought exactly the same. Thanks for asking this question. That being said in such a case I might even go with `episodes-2011` (if that doesn't prompt users to use it for any TV episode from 2011, but ok, there has to be a line somewhere).

Comment: Aaand...[people still use it](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/32258/49). Probably simply because typing *"episodes"* and clicking the first tag that appears is quite easy. So we could go with `episodes-tv` as well, then.

Comment: Aaand...[a very good recent one](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/36812/49)!

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Sarcasm?

Comment: @Catija No, why? It's a good example for the misuse of the tag.

Answer (score 2):

**I'd rather opt for [episodes-2011](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episodes-2011).**

While you are correct in that the currently established way here would be either [episodes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episodes) or [episodes-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episodes-tv), I also agree that they are very ambiguous and likely to be used for any question about a TV-show's episodes.

However, **I think this is to a large degree equally bad for [episodes-tv-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episodes-tv-series)**. Even if that is admittedly only anecdotal evidence, I feel that people indeed use that tag now and then for totally unrelated questions, likely because it looks as if it's about "episodes of a TV series" (in fact I just recently accidentally removed it from a question *where it actually was correctly used*, merely because I was naturally conditioned to think that this tag is usually misplaced anyway ;-)).

Given that it would also set a wrong precedent, since we [explicitly decided against the use of `-tv-series` as tag appendage](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1070/49), **I think [episodes-2011](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episodes-2011) would be a good compromise**. It would on the one hand use an established practice from this site's tagging strategies and on the other hand it also might be a bit more specific. While people could still mistake it for meaning "any episodes from 2011", this is a less likely interpretation than "episodes of a TV series" for the `-tv-series` version. (Of course this still won't guard us from people just typing `episodes...` and being satisfied with the first tag that appears, no matter if it has some appendage, but this can't be prevented anyway. At least the `-2011` should make them aware of it being somehow "special", or more "special" than `-tv-series`.)

Comment: I don't think `episodes-2011` is a particularly good pick either. Its not clear that if I want to ask a question about the Episodes tv series that I should use `episodes-2011`, especially if I dont know that the show was made in 2011. What about `episodes-showtime-series` or something?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Good point, I admittedly had more the misuses than the actually correct usages in mind. Though, your suggestion isn't particularly good either IMHO, since it introduces too much clutter. I don't think it's good practice, even in just a single case, to include the production studio/TV-channel in the tag.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I disagree. You're going about it backwards. Someone asking a question isn't going to have to know that it's from 2011... the wiki excerpt will include the fact that it's a Showtime Series. All we're trying to do is find a clear, concise way to prevent people from tagging every question about a specific episode of a tv show "episodes"... which the -2011 should do.